circle displaying in the middle of the splash screen in flutter
i wanted to modify the splash/launch screen in flutter so after modyfying the lauch_background.xml file to change the background and image , the background changed fine but noe there is a white cicle showing in the middle of the screen and i would want to know how to get rid of this
this is the code for the launch_background. xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_color" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/dimba" />
    </item>
</layer-list>

and this is how the screen looks like now
i tried changing the styles.xml but its still there

Remove this:
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/dimba" />
</item>


That worked thanks a lot finally after days of searching ! but how would I be able to place my image at the center? @Phan

You can use this code and add your android:src(your logo with more space). Replace @drawable/dimba by your logo
